# How to add hash password to database?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `store()` in controller, and in this place I call 3 functions. Variable `$users` store correct fields validation with values them. In next step I call function which hash password. At the end I call function which add user to database. My problem is that hash password is not add to database.What can I do that pass hashPassword to `createUser()` ?

```
 public function store(RegistrationRequest $request, UserService $user)
{
     $user = $request->correctValidate();  
     $userService->hashPassword($user['password']);
     $userService->createUser($user);
}

public function createUser($request): void
{
    User::create($request);
}

public function hashPassword($request)
{
    return Hash::make($request);
}

public function correctValidate()
{
    return $this->validated();
}
```

Comment: Post the signature for the `hashPassword` method.

Comment: @bassxzero `hashPassword()` are good, this function hash password, but I ask how can I pass hash password to `createUser()` ?

Comment: well, post then the `createUser()`  function so we can see what happens there, and is `$users` more than 1? else you need to itterate over them.

Comment: Is `$users` the user you want to add, you probably need to hash the password on that rather than on `$user`.

Comment: @Dorvalla User is only one, I modify my post and add functions

Comment: you are hashing the password in `hashPassword` but not doing anything with the result

Comment: @apokryfos So what can I do with this result

Comment: `$user['password'] = $userService->hashPassword($user['password']);` should work

Answer (score 0):

@Deks2 Please try below solution:

`$user['password'] = $userService->hashPassword($user['password']);`